# News reader to keep up with world news outside social media

Tags: osx, ios, feed-reader

Due to the recent developments with Facebook, I have decided to walk away from the social media platforms. I honestly just needed a reason to do so, since my main activity on Facebook is to keep up with news. It offers an easy and convenient way to organize and display your most preferred sources.

What news aggregator do you use in your daily life and why? Is RSS still a thing?

I am on a Mac and I don't mind paying for a good product as long as it is supported and also available for iOS.

Comment: So you are looking for an alternative to **fake news** from **FaKebook**?

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer [Feedly](https://feedly.com). Pro version is not free but has a nice feature - to mute any news related to selected topics.

Answer (score 0):

As far as web based RSS readers go I like [InoReader](https://www.inoreader.com). It is fairly customizable, as a nice-ish UI, though there are certainly many other offers around the web tailored to suit every taste.

Advantage is it keeps read items synced across wherever you have internet access, plus there's an accompanying [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.innologica.inoreader) if you are so inclined.

If you prefer an offline sort of thing, or syncing is not required there are also many standalone RSS readers from full featured complete like [RSS Guard](https://github.com/martinrotter/rssguard) or [QuiteRSS](https://quiterss.org/en) down to minimal solutions like [Desktop Ticker](http://www.battware.co.uk/desktopticker.htm) or [Feed notifier](https://www.feednotifier.com/) among [many others](https://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?sc=1).

There are also many extension based solutions for both [Chromium family](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/rss?_category=extensions) and [Mozilla family](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?platform=windows&q=rss) web browsers like some even available on both like [Feedbro](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/feedbro/mefgmmbdailogpfhfblcnnjfmnpnmdfa)